# How to receive ASP.NET LocalResources resx string

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resx

I have in my ASP.NET Web Forms Application resx file localized in App_LocalResources\fr.aspx.resx with key value: hello_world.

Now I want to use it on my ASPxLabel on class Page.aspx, so I simply:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="0" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:fr, hello_world %>"></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

but I have error: Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'msg' was not found.

I am sure that fr.aspx.resx is publicated, but still got Parser Error. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check the name of your resource file. It has to follow the following naming convension

```
pageName.extension.language.resx
```

If you aspx page name Page.aspx, then the you should have resource files with the following name.(You can add resource files for further language and culture)

```
Page.aspx.fr.resx
```

Check whether you follow this convension or not.

To you this resource in the aspx page you have to follow the convension as below

```
<%$Resources:Class,ResourceID%>
```

where Class is the name of resource file, if it is compiled as class, otherwise this can be ignored.
ResourceId is the key in the resource file.
In your code you are setting the resource as below. Check whether the resource file has a codebehind with the class name fr.

```
Text="<%$ Resources:fr, hello_world %>">
```

For more details you can visit the following link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok. My page is Acceuil.aspx, so to follow convension I change: App_LocalResources\Accueil.aspx.fr.resx

and Text="<%$ Resources:Accueil, hello_world %>"> still give me "The resource object with key 'hello_world' was not found."

Comment: How many languages do you need to support? If fr is the default language then please delete .fr. in the resource file name. You should name your resource file as App_LocalResources\Accueil.aspx.resx. If you have code behind for this (Accueil.aspx.resx.cs) then check the class name. If you dont have codebehind then change to <%$ Resources:hello_world %>

Comment: Yes it helps. I was only supporting one default language and after I delete .fr it solve a problem.